# Python - how to check if one of several conditions is met and then specifically if each of conditions is met?

Tags: python

I am wondering if there is any shortcut to do the following:

```
if a or b or c ...
    do p
    if a
        do x
    if b
        do y
    if c
        do z
    ...
else
    do q
```

Is it necessary to type out each of the conditions twice or is there any other way to do this?

Comment: What are the real actions and conditions? Maybe there is another way, that is specific to the problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code, but if checking any of `a`, `b` or `c` is expensive, you could use a flag instead, as to check the condition only once:

```
flag = False
if a:
    flag = True
    do x
if b:
    flag = True
    do y
if c:
    flag = True
    do z
do (p if flag else q)
```

I find this form also more readable as it only has one level of indentation, but I suppose that this is just a matter of preference...

---

**EDIT:** If `p` must be executed before `x`, `y`, `z`, then you could store the result of the condition checking instead:

```
doers = [x, y, z]
conditions = [check(el) for el in (a, b, c)]
do (p if any(conditions) else q)
tmp = [doers[i] for i, condition in enumerate(conditions) if condition]
```

(the line with `tmp` would be more pythonic with a real `for` loop, but I understand that you are optimising performance, and list comprehension is faster...)

Comment: +1, This is good, but what if `p` needs to be done before `x` etc?